# Scripting in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, references

Can anyone suggest me web-links to learn scripting in GRASS GIS (its utilities, examples etc.) other than those available in GRASS official Wiki/Sites?

Comment: what kinds of things are you interested in doing in your scripts? are you thinking of basic scripts to automate and recall actions, or more complex programs?

Comment: Currently I am thinking of implementing basic repetitive tasks like performing supervised classification on different groups/subgroups in a mapset. But I am interested to know about complex implementation scenarios as well.

Comment: What kind of examples are you looking for? e.g. shell, bash, or python scripts?

Comment: I am mainly looking for shell/bash scripts. If it's important I use GRASS in Ubuntu 11.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get some Grass shell examples on [GRASS lists](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/GRASS-f1837859.html).
Try to run a search on [shell](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=search_page&node=1837859&query=shell) or [bash script](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=search_page&node=1837859&query=bash%20script&days=0). Looking at users script online is a good approach to understand how it works.

You will find few snippets on [that page](http://geoinformatics.fsv.cvut.cz/gwiki/On_scripting_GRASS_GIS%3a_Building_location-independent_command_line_tools) and also links to references (on the bottom of the page). See also Appendix 2 of that [online ressource](http://www.scribd.com/doc/54556188/112/GRASS-shell-scripts) by M. Neteler. Some others examples are also available on GRASS [book](http://www.grassbook.org/).

From what I know the GRASS wiki is probably one of the best resource to learn GRASS scripting.